# Habitability and orbital stability of these moons?

Tags: moons, orbital-mechanics, habitability

These moons orbit a Jovian planet with 0.52 Jovian mass and at 1.02 AU from a star with 0.98 Sol mass.

3.85 Days, 0.351 Earth, 0.68 G

15.4 Days, 0.242 Earth, 0.59 G

30.8 Days, 0.118 Earth, 0.44 G

Is tidal heating enough to produce a molten core that will create a magnetic field for all three moons? Does this resonance appear stable?

I created two intelligent races inhabit the first two moons, they are in a bitter dispute over the third moon and who owns it, it's similar to Mars but with some small lakes and streams.

Comment: A 1.02 and .98 in the same sentence its killing me, just so you know. Control the CDO ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your Jovian planet is anything like Jupiter the appalling amount of radiation and frequent meteor impacts will make it tough for life to develop. 
Furthermore tidal heating may keep the insulated core of a planet molten but that doesn't really benefit the surface, not unless the tidal forces are so strong that heat is generated almost as fast as the surface can radiate it. Any faster and your planet, which is already a volcanic hell, will continue to heat up until it's radiating enough heat for an equilibrium to occur, i.e. the surface becomes molten.

Comment: At 0.52 Jupiter masses I think radiation will be less of an issue?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things that aren't simply proportional to mass. The most important thing is the strength of the planet's magnetic field, and all we know from the Solar System is that the relationship of that to the size and rotation of the planet is complicated.

Comment: I think I might need to make the gas giant larger, i'm not sure its hill sphere is large enough to hold onto the last moon.